# How to subset data

Tags: stata

I am using Stata and I need to subset my data. I would like to create a subset of data in which all the observations related to a unique id are maintained if in one of the observations related to the unique id meets a certain criterion. For example, I want to keep all semester observations (variable `recordnum`) related to a student (variable `id`), if in one of the semesters they were enrolled they received a aid (variable `aid`).

Comment: http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata contains information highly applicable here, i.e. how to give data examples we can work with. Just giving variable names is not enough, especially as you show no attempt whatever at code. The answer will pivot on `if` so consulting the help for that qualifier is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution. Might be able to do it in 1 line though.

you need the variable `aid` to be 0 or 1.
then:

```
bys id: egen temp = max(aid) 
keep if temp == 1 
drop temp
```

If the variable `aid` is not 0 or 1 (for instance, value of the aid in $, TRUE or FALSE), you can create if using the `if`:

```
gen dummy_aid = 0 
replace dummy_aid = 1 if aid >0 
* ( or if aid == TRUE, etc...)
```

Comment: Corrected some non-Stata syntax. Note that for `aid` a (0, 1) variable `bysort id (aid) : keep if a[_N]` is a one-line alternative to your first block and `gen dummy_id = aid > 0` to your second block.

Comment: `aid[_N]` not `a[_N]` above.